# JNI OpenCV Android draw function line or rectangle

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a large problem with drawn function in my android jni app using OpenCV. I track objects in my native function and forward rectangles Vector by Mat to Java code, then draw  rectangles on RGBA Mat in Java and it all works. But now, I have draw these rectangles in native code in my function before return to Java, but it doesn't work. I tried to draw anything from the jni, but still no effect. Drawn functions doesn't change the Mat, which turn into Java. I would be very grateful for help.

This is my native code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeDetect
(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass, jlong thiz, jlong imageGray, jlong faces)
{
    LOGD("Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeDetect enter");
    try
    {
        vector<Rect> RectFaces;
        ((DetectionBasedTracker*)thiz)->process(*((Mat*)imageGray));
        ((DetectionBasedTracker*)thiz)->getObjects(RectFaces);
        for(int i=0; i<RectFaces.size(); i++)
        {
            Point p,k;
            p.x = ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).x;
            p.y = ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).y;
            k.x = ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).x + ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).width;
            k.y = ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).y + ((Rect)RectFaces[i]).height;
            rectangle(*((Mat*)imageGray), p, k,Scalar(0,255,255, 255), -1, 8);
        }
        vector_Rect_to_Mat(RectFaces, *((Mat*)faces));
    }
    catch(cv::Exception& e)
    {
        LOGD("nativeCreateObject caught cv::Exception: %s", e.what());
        jclass je = jenv->FindClass("org/opencv/core/CvException");
        if(!je)
            je = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        jenv->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LOGD("nativeDetect caught unknown exception");
        jclass je = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        jenv->ThrowNew(je, "Unknown exception in JNI code {highgui::VideoCapture_n_1VideoCapture__()}");
    }
    LOGD("Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeDetect exit");
}
```

and java code which return rgba Mat:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();
        //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mCanny, CANNY_MIN_TRESHOLD, CANNY_MAX_TRESHOLD);
        Point center = new Point(mRgba.width() / 2, mRgba.height() / 2);
        //must be 1 channels 8 bit!
        /*//do Hough transform to find lines
        double rho = 1;
        double theta = Math.PI/180;
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mCanny, mLines, rho, theta, HOUGH_TRESHOLD, HOUGH_MIN_LINE_LENGTH, HOUGH_MAX_LINE_GAP);*/

        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
            mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
        }

        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

        if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2,
                        2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize),
                        new Size());
        } else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
            if (mNativeDetector != null)
                mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
                //mNativeDetector.findLines(mGray, mCanny);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
        }

        /*Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
            if (center.x > facesArray[i].tl().x
                    && center.x < facesArray[i].br().x) {
                if (center.y > facesArray[i].tl().y
                        && center.y < facesArray[i].br().y) {
                    Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(),
                            facesArray[i].br(), CAR_RECT_COLOR_RED, 3);
                } else {
                    Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(),
                            facesArray[i].br(), CAR_RECT_COLOR_YELLOW, 3);
                }
            } else {
                Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(),
                        CAR_RECT_COLOR_YELLOW, 3);
            }
        }*/

        Point p1 = new Point(mRgba.width() / 2, 0);
        Point p2 = new Point(mRgba.width() / 2, mRgba.height());

        Point p3 = new Point(0, mRgba.height() / 2);
        Point p4 = new Point(mRgba.width(), mRgba.height() / 2);

        Core.line(mRgba, p3, p4, AXIS_COLOR);
        Core.line(mRgba, p1, p2, AXIS_COLOR);


        return mRgba;
        //return mLines;
    }
```

Comment: Hah, I feel stupid now...I have given to the function grayscale Mat  instead of RGBA :(

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing a gray-scale image to the function?
If you want to show things up on the screen, you should pass RGBA data.

Comment: Yes,thanks I have corrected it, but now the application behaves strangely. I don't know too much on the lifecycle in android app, but after some 20-30 seconds the main window of the application goes to the background. I will mention that I am using only onCameraFrame (), which produces native code.